# Separate YouTube, Downloadable, and simple URL link from same text in PHP

Tags: php, regex, algorithm, youtube, preg-replace

For normal link

```
$content = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?((/[\w/_\.%\-+~]*)?(\?\S+)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $content);
```

For Download link

```
$content = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?/[\w/_\.%\-+~]+(\.exe|\.mp3|\.pdf|\.rar|\.doc|\.jar|\.ppt|\.xls|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.mp4|\.avi|\.mkv|\.flv|\.3gp|\.mms|\.sis|\.sisx|\.jad|\.mdi|\.qcp)(\?\S+)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">Download</a>', $content);
```

For Youtube Link

```
// Replace Youtube URLs with embed code
function embedYoutube($text)
{

$search = '%          # Match any youtube URL in the wild.
    (?:https?://)?    # Optional scheme. Either http or https
    (?:www\.)?        # Optional www subdomain
    (?:               # Group host alternatives
      youtu\.be/      # Either youtu.be,
    | youtube\.com    # or youtube.com
      (?:             # Group path alternatives
        /embed/       # Either /embed/
      | /v/           # or /v/
      | /watch\?v=    # or /watch\?v=
      )               # End path alternatives.
    )                 # End host alternatives.
    ([\w\-]{10,12})   # Allow 10-12 for 11 char youtube id.
    \b                # Anchor end to word boundary.
    %x';
    $replace = '<object width="425" height="344">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/$1?fs=1"</param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/$1?fs=1"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowFullScreen="true" width="425" height="344">
    </embed>
    </object>';

  return preg_replace($search, $replace, $text);
 }
```

I'm using this but I want to apply all of these on same text, while not affecting output of each other.

e.g.

```
$content = "Download this song http://songs.com/song1.mp3  
Watch it Video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YR12Z8f1Dh8  
and click here for more details http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Song"
```

will produce this

```
Download this song <br />
<a href="http://songs.com/song1.mp3" target="_blank">Download</a>
Watch it Video <br />
<object width="425" height="344">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/YR12Z8f1Dh8?fs=1"</param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/YR12Z8f1Dh8?fs=1"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowFullScreen="true" width="425" height="344">
    </embed>        </object>
and click here for more details <br />
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Song" target="_blank">http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Song</a>
```

Can I solve this with a common regular expression or by any PHP methodology?

Comment: Please provide some input examples, those you have in the $context variable before running the regex.

Comment: Are the lines of each link always line breaked?

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli  examples is provided now

Comment: Is there no body to answer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `preg_match_all` with the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` option to find all of the URLs with their offsets, rewrite each URL, use the offsets to extract the interstitial text, and put everything back together.